# Cannot View nor Delete Folders

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1703

This has been happening since I upgraded windows to v1703. Many of the folders in `%appdata%` and other places including `%programdata%` are all in-accessible, one instance was an install of Discord, giving a bunch of permission-related errors.

I attempted to fix this by deleting the folder & reinstalling but it gives me Access is Denied or requires permission from my administrator (which is me, I am the only user account):

[image: Access-Denied]
[image: Admin-Required]

Following my own knowledge, I open up security settings and am greeted by:

[image: Security Settings]

Seeing the weird `Read permissions` message, I open `Advanced` and am greeted by this:

[image: Advanced Settings]

Clicking `Continue`:

[image: ShareAdmin]

This confuses me, as it states that `Administrators` have full control of this folder, as well as `everyone`, yet I cannot access nor edit this folder?

Is there any possible way to fix this without having to revert back to an old version of windows (and possibly still having this issue?)?

Comment: Your ability to revert back to 1607 has long expired considering it’s been more then 15 days since you upgraded (more like 6 months)

Comment: Nope, it's v1703. I only updated a couple of days ago.

Comment: Never said it wasn’t 1703, for its been less then 15 days, and you have not use the Cleanup tool then you can revert back to 1607

Comment: Oh. Yes. I still can revert back. I see what you mean. I was seeing if there was another way before I did revert back though.

Comment: Your permissions are all screwed up, you should revert, to verify that problem is resolved.

Comment: Reverting fixed it. Oh well.